# Using CodeMirror to highlight text in textarea?

Tags: html, codemirror

I have a textarea that on button click will be filled with the contents of a certain file. I am trying to implement CodeMirror that will automatically highlight the syntax of the code that is loaded into the textarea.

Comment: Are you trying to switch it's mode based on what has been filled?  Do you know what the language of the file is when you are loading it?

Comment: Yes, I know what language so it doesn't need to be able to detect multiple languages. I'm just trying to get it to recognize html and perform syntax highlighting upon entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure you have the proper mode js files loaded (look at the external resources in the fiddle) and then it's as simple as a `setValue` call.

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/mssrahz1/1/

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "htmlmixed"
});

var loadButton = document.getElementById("load");
loadButton.onclick = function () {
    // here you'd load your file and then call setValue with the result
    myCodeMirror.setValue("<div>Hi There</div>\n<ul>\n\t<li>one</li>\n</ul>");
};
```